# C printing specific char depending on input from string with pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

Given this:

```
 char c[]={ '0', 0, 'o', 'a', 'i', 'e' };

 char s_format[] = { "\nBra"
   "v%c!\n" };
```

The object of this program is to print different lines of code depending on the input, which can be:

```
                            OUTPUT
 ./nameofmyfile             Bravo
 ./nameofmyfile mp          Bravi
 ./nameofmyfile f           Brava
 ./nameofmyfile fp          Brave
```

In my main I have two char pointers:

```
char *q = c;      //this one is initialized at position c[0]
char *p = NULL;
```

I suppose I could use only the *q pointer in order to print either the character o, i, a or e in the s_format without using a switch construct.

Would this for loop be perhaps correct?

```
for (unsigned int i=2; i<sizeof(c); ++i) {
     printf("%c", *(q+i), s_format[4]);
}
```

Or should I perhaps use a series of if's?

```
if ( argc > 3 && strlen(argv[3]) ) {
    if ( *(argv[3]) == 'f' )
        i = 3;
}

if ( argc > 4 && strlen(argv[4]) ) {
    if ( *(argv[4]) == 'mp' )
        i = 4;
}

if ( argc > 1 && strlen(argv[5]) ) {
    if ( *(argv[5]) == 'fp' )
        i = 5;
}
```

Comment: You have one extra parameter in `printf("%c", *(q+i), s_format[4])`. Overall it is not clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Your loop has absolutely nothing to do with the problem. It would rather seem that you want to overwrite `s_format[4]` with another character. And why do you store a line feed at index 0 for?

Comment: Is it perhaps the *(q+i) one? Is there any other (string related or not) printing function I could use to print the value of the pointer q as it increments with i all within the array s_format? Or perhaps I could use this line of code in the for loop: `s_format[4]=*(q+i); printf("%c", s_format);` ?

Comment: I apologize for the unclear question; unfortunately I have no idea how to get that output and the loop was my best guess (first program in c ever). How could I get those outputs, and do I have to use the s_format string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting here my answer for the Others:

```
if(argc>1 && strlen(argv[1])>1 && argv[1][1]==p[0])
     i+=2;
printf(s_format, q[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

char c[]={ '0', 0, 'o', 'a', 'i', 'e' };

const char * s_begin = "Brav";
const char * s_end ="!\n";

int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    printf("%s%c%s",  s_begin,c[i],s_end); //prints brava
    return 0;
}
```

if you accept my proposition, you can upvote it by clicking on the upper arrow and you can also accept the answer by pressing the V

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want something like

```
int *q = c;
if (argc == 2) {
    if (argv[1][0] == 'f') {
        if (argv[1][1] == 'p') { //assume argv[1][2] == 0
            q += 5;
        } else {
            q += 3; //assume argv[1][1] == 0
        }
    } else { //assume argv[1][0] == 'm'; argv[1][1] == 'p'; argv[1][2] = 0
        q += 4;
    }
} else { //assume argc == 1
    q += 2;
}
printf(s_format, *q);
```

Comment: But I've just noticed that the output needs to be "Bravo" with any input, even bad ones (like ./nameofmyfile 429tfyh), and unfortunately this way still gives me the output "Bravo". Any tips on how to achieve that?

Comment: When I say "assume" make the code be sure about that before updating `q`.